# AWS elastic beanstalk cannot return custom response code using resteasy?

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, resteasy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on a web service using RESTEASY to set the response status code when get some exception. 
First I tried resteasy exception mapper which works fine locally. The mapper code attached below. However, when I upload that WS into elastic beanstalk, that always return 500 (internal server error).

```
@Provider
public class LoadGridTileFailedExceptionMapper extends BaseExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<LoadGridTileFailedException>
{
@Override
public Response toResponse(LoadGridTileFailedException e)
{
    log(e.getMessage(), e);
    return printMsg(e.getMessage(), DtmWebServiceReturnStatus.LOAD_GRID_TILE_FAILED_EXCEPTION_CODE);
}
}
```

Then I try just throw exception WebApplicationException(ex, DtmWebServiceReturnStatus.LOAD_GRID_TILE_FAILED_EXCEPTION_CODE) to get around exception mapping. The result is that I got a response status 498(LOAD_GRID_TILE_FAILED_EXCEPTION_CODE) wrapped in status code 500.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 - Error report

## HTTP Status 498 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** http.498

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.27

It seems that elastic beanstalk wrapped all exceptions throw out in the server side with status code 500?The question is how can I get around that feature and return the status code I set in response? Thank you.

---

### UPDATE

Try more requests this morning and find something interesting:

### Get the right return status in elastic beanstalk log snapshot

### /var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access_log.txt

127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:28 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:31 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:34 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:37 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:39 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:41 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:44 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:48 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:51 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:54 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:57 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22

---

### /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log

10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:28 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"
10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:31 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"
10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:34 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"
10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:37 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"
10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:39 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"
10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:41 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"
10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:44 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"
10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:48 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"
10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:51 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"
10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:54 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"
10.28.215.233 (65.167.11.254, 10.28.215.233) - - [09/Jan/2013:15:06:57 +0000] "GET /published/tile/003331330031 HTTP/1.1" 498 22 "-" "-"

### However in client side, still got 500 :-(

### printMsg method:

```
protected Response printMsg(String msg, int intStatus)
{
    // Need this due to the Resteasy bug
    ServiceDataCollector.processRequest(true);

    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(intStatus);
    builder.type("text/plain");
    builder.entity("ERROR: " + msg);
    Response rep = builder.build();
    LOG.error(rep.getStatus() + ":" + rep.toString());
    return rep;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your source to printMsg?

Answer (score -1):

Some one help me to work the problem out. I had the httpd deployed in my AMI before tomcat server at 80. So the load balancer will interact with httpd server, which change the status code from tomcat to 500. Disable that httpd server will solve the problem. Thx for everyone's help.